# Understanding Many to Many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am following the official documentation of laravel.
I am trying to establish a relationship between `users` and `roles`.
So, the tables are:
`users` | `roles` | `role_user`

Here `role_user` is my pivot table.

Now in `User` model I defined the relationship as follows:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

So here in return statement block it says `belongsToMany('App\Role')`. But a user can only have one role right? either administrator or subscriber etc
Or it is called many to many in the context many roles are associated with many users ?

Comment: Since you're using many-to-many relationship, a user can have many roles. If you want a user to have only one role, use one-to-many relationship instead.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin So if my application demands only one role for a user, then can I use one to one in that scenario ?

Comment: Not one-to-one but one-to-many. User `belongsTo()` Role and Role `hasMany()` users.

Comment: He said that you can use One to Many! But you can't use One to One!

Comment: thank you sir                                                                                                      got it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many-to-many relationship used for a user can have many roles. As you told that your application demands only one role for a user, then use  One to Many. But you can't use One to One in that case.

So your relationship look like this:

User belongsTo() Role and Role hasMany() users.

**In User model:**

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

**In Role model:**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Hope this helps you!